# On distributivity

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that $a\times (x+y)=a\times x + a\times y =(x+y)\times a$ and $a+(\min(x,y))=\min(a+x,a+y)=(\min(x,y))+a$.

Is there a natural non-trivial $\circ$ such that $a\circ(x\times y)=(a\circ x)\times(a\circ y)=(x\times y)\circ a$?

I want both right and left distributivity and assume we are over natural numbers.

Or else exponentiation works.

Comment: What about $a\circ x=x$? Or do you want some other conditions to hold?

Comment: Probably $a\circ x=x^a$ is closer to what you want, but then you might need to restrict to $a,x>0$.

Answer (score 2):

In positive integer arithmetic, if you define $a \circ x = x^a$. then you have
$$
a \circ (x \times y) = (x \times y)^a = x^a \times y^a =   (a \circ x) \times (a \circ y)
$$
(To extend this to larger number systems, you need to be careful about when $x^a$ is well-defined.)

Comment: +1. Note that distributivity on the *right* fails: $(x\times y)\circ a\not=(x\circ a)\times (y\circ a)$.

Comment: Noah: thanks for the cautionary remark.